# Ajax to Asmx request works only on localhost

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, localhost, asmx

This is request:

```
            var xCoordinateString = 111;
            var yCoordinateString = 111;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "InsertCoordinates.asmx/Insert",
                data: { xCoordinates: xCoordinateString, yCoordinates: yCoordinateString },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('yes');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('no');
                } 

            });
```

This is Insert function in webservice:

```
public void Insert(string xCoordinates, string yCoordinates)
        {
            string[] xCoords = xCoordinates.Split(',');
            string[] yCoords = yCoordinates.Split(',');

            //The following is a ZIP operation which allows you to do a foreach loop on two arrays.
            var xANDyCoordinates = xCoords.Zip(yCoords, (x, y) => new { xCoord = x, yCoord = y });

            foreach (var xy in xANDyCoordinates)
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertIndividualHeatMapCoordinates", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("xCoord", xy.xCoord));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("yCoord", xy.yCoord));                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }            
        }
```

But, it pushes data only when I access my server using remote desktop connection and open `http://localhost:8032/`

When using my machine and accessing `http://networkname11:8032/` - (Aborted)

[image]

Comment: Do all requests to your machine conclude to abort state?

Comment: no, it's working in another project where I use: $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CS.aspx/SaveUser",
            data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                window.location = "http://google.com";
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('nope');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

Comment: It seems that might be a network issue such as dns or resolving problems, have it a look